# WinUI 3 Button with a command in the GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, devexpress, winui-3

Using WinUI 3 with latest version of DevExpress.

I would like to have a Button with a Command property with a CommandParameter in the DevExpress.WinUI.Grid.
Everything in the application is a Page and following MVVM pattern with dependency injection.
The command doesn't get executed when the button is clicked.
At very least I would like to see Button actually executing.

> **XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="CSA2.Views.SearchUserPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CSA2.Views"
    xmlns:vm="using:CSA2.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:dxe="using:DevExpress.WinUI.Editors"
    xmlns:grid="using:DevExpress.WinUI.Grid"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ic="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="ContentArea"
                Margin="{StaticResource SmallTopBottomMargin}">
        <ScrollViewer Height="450" ZoomMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
            <StackPanel Margin="0 0 10 0">
                <TextBlock x:Uid="SearchUser" Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <Grid x:Name="userGrid" DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="UserNameText"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="5 0 5 0"/>
                            <dxe:TextEdit x:Uid="UserNameNullText"
                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          Margin="0 0 5 0"
                                          Width="200"
                                          Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="UserEmailText"
                                       Grid.Column="2"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                            <dxe:TextEdit x:Uid="UserEmailNullText"
                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                          Grid.Column="3"
                                          Width="200"
                                          Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserEmail, Mode= TwoWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Uid="UserRoleText"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="4"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="5 0 5 0"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="5"
                                    Margin="0 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Select"
                                                   Margin="0 0 10 0" />
                                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE70D;"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Button.Flyout>
                                    <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <ListView x:Name="UserRoles" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.UserRoles, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                      SelectionMode="Multiple"
                                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                                      ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
                                                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                    <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                                        <ic:InvokeCommandAction
                                                            Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedUserRolesCommand}"
                                                            CommandParameter="{x:Bind UserRoles.SelectedItems,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                                    </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                            </ListView>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Flyout>
                                </Button.Flyout>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="6"
                                    Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                    Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchCommand}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Uid="SearchButtonText"
                                               Margin="0 0 10 0" />
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Zoom"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="5"
                                    Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddUserCommand}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Uid="AddButtonText" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="AddFriend"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="6"
                                    Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                    Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClearCommand}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock x:Uid="ClearButtonText" Margin="0 0 20 0"/>
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Refresh"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 5 0 5">
                        <grid:GridControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Source, Mode = OneWay}"
                                          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <grid:GridControl.Columns>
                                <grid:GridTextColumn FieldName="UserName" Header="User Name"/>
                                <grid:GridTextColumn FieldName="UserEmail" Header="User Email"/>
                                <grid:GridCheckBoxColumn FieldName="UserActiveIndicator" Header="User Status" />
                                <grid:GridDateColumn FieldName="RecordCreated" Header="Date Created"/>
                                <grid:GridDateColumn FieldName="RecordModified" Header="Date Modified"/>
                                <grid:GridTemplateColumn
                                    Header="Edit"
                                    HeaderHorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    FixedWidth="True"
                                    Width="81">
                                    <grid:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.EditUserCommand, ElementName=userGrid}">
                                                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Edit"/>
                                            </Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </grid:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </grid:GridTemplateColumn>
                            </grid:GridControl.Columns>
                        </grid:GridControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Expander Grid.Row="2" Margin="0 10 0 5"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Expander.Header><TextBlock Text="Dashboard View"/>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <Expander.Content>
                            <TabView SelectedIndex="0" MinHeight="275" TabItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TabItems}"
                                     IsAddTabButtonVisible="False">
                                <TabView.TabItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TabViewItem Header="{Binding Header}" IsClosable="False">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail}" />
                                        </TabViewItem>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </TabView.TabItemTemplate>
                            </TabView>
                        </Expander.Content>
                    </Expander>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

> **ViewModel**

```C#
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CSA2.Contracts.Services;
using CSA2.Contracts.ViewModels;
using CSA2.Core.Contracts.Services;
using CSA2.Models;

namespace CSA2.ViewModels;

public class SearchUserViewModel : ObservableRecipient, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly IUserDataService _userDataService;

    private string? _searchText;

    private IList<object>? _selectedUserRoles;
    private List<User> _userDataStore;
    private string? _userEmail;
    private string? _userName;

    private List<UserRole> _userRoles;
    private List<UserRole> _userRolesStore;

    public SearchUserViewModel(IUserDataService userDataService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _selectedUserRoles = new List<object>();
        _userDataService = userDataService;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _userRoles = new List<UserRole>();
        _userRolesStore = new List<UserRole>();
        TabItems = new ObservableCollection<ObservableObject>();
        SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(Handle_SearchUsers);
        ClearCommand = new RelayCommand(Handle_ClearData);
        SelectedUserRolesCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Handle_SelectedUserRoles);
        AddUserCommand = new RelayCommand(Handle_AddUser);
        EditUserCommand = new RelayCommand(Handle_EditUser);
        TabItems.Add(new DetailTabViewModel("Tab1"));
        TabItems.Add(new DetailTabViewModel("Tab2"));
        TabItems.Add(new DetailTabViewModel("Tab3"));
    }

    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get;
    }

    public ICommand ClearCommand
    {
        get;
    }

    public ICommand SelectedUserRolesCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ICommand AddUserCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ICommand EditUserCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Source
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new();

    public List<UserRole> SelectedUserRoles
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new();

    public string? SearchText
    {
        get => _searchText;
        set => SetProperty(ref _searchText, value);
    }

    public List<UserRole> UserRoles
    {
        get => _userRoles;
        set => SetProperty(ref _userRoles, value);
    }

    public string? UserEmail
    {
        get => _userEmail;
        set => SetProperty(ref _userEmail, value);
    }

    public string? UserName
    {
        get => _userName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _userName, value);
    }

    public async void OnNavigatedTo(object parameter)
    {
        var data = await _userDataService.GetUserRoleData<List<UserRole>>();

        _userRolesStore = new List<UserRole>
        {
            new() { UserRoleDescription = "Super User", UserRoleId = 1 },
            new() { UserRoleDescription = "RS User", UserRoleId = 2 }
        };
        Source.Clear();
        UserRoles = _userRolesStore;
        _userDataStore = GetUsers();
        SearchUsers();
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom()
    {
    }

    private void Handle_EditUser()
    {
        var poo = 1;
    }

    private void Handle_SelectedUserRoles(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            _selectedUserRoles = obj as IList<object>;

            if (_selectedUserRoles != null && _selectedUserRoles.Any())
            {
                ProcessSelectedFlyoutItems(_selectedUserRoles);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessSelectedFlyoutItems(IList<object>? selectedItems)
    {
        if (selectedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in selectedItems)
            {
                if (item is UserRole userRole)
                {
                    if (!SelectedUserRoles.Contains(item))
                    {
                        SelectedUserRoles.Add(userRole);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Handle_ClearData() => Clear();

    private void Clear()
    {
        SearchText = string.Empty;
        UserName = string.Empty;
        UserEmail = string.Empty;
        Source.Clear();
        _selectedUserRoles?.Clear();
        SelectedUserRoles?.Clear();
    }

    private void Handle_SearchUsers() => SearchUsers();

    private void SearchUsers()
    {
        var userRoles = SelectedUserRoles;
        List<User> selectedUsers;
        var users = _userDataStore;
        if (userRoles.Any())
        {
            selectedUsers = users.Where(u => userRoles.All(ur => u.UserRoles.All(ur2 => ur2 == ur.UserRoleId)))
                .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            selectedUsers = _userDataStore;
        }


        foreach (var user in selectedUsers)
        {
            Source.Add(user);
        }
    }

    private List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = new List<User>
        {
            new()
            {
                UserId = 1,
                UserName = "Joe Smith",
                UserEmail = "joesmith@company.com",
                Departments = new List<int>(),
                RecordCreated = DateTime.Today,
                RecordModified = DateTime.Today,
                UserRoles = new List<int> { 1 },
                UserActiveIndicator = true
            },
            new()
            {
                UserId = 2,
                UserName = "Mary Lamb",
                UserEmail = "marylamb@company.com",
                Departments = new List<int>(),
                RecordCreated = DateTime.Today,
                RecordModified = DateTime.Today,
                UserRoles = new List<int> { 1 },
                UserActiveIndicator = true
            },
            new()
            {
                UserId = 3,
                UserName = "Sam Iam",
                UserEmail = "SamIam@company.com",
                Departments = new List<int>(),
                RecordCreated = DateTime.Today,
                RecordModified = DateTime.Today,
                UserRoles = new List<int> { 1 },
                UserActiveIndicator = true
            },
            new()
            {
                UserId = 4,
                UserName = "Will Row",
                UserEmail = "WillRow@company.com",
                Departments = new List<int>(),
                RecordCreated = DateTime.Today,
                RecordModified = DateTime.Today,
                UserRoles = new List<int> { 1 },
                UserActiveIndicator = true
            },
            new()
            {
                UserId = 5,
                UserName = "LoeSee",
                UserEmail = "LoeSeew@company.com",
                Departments = new List<int>(),
                RecordCreated = DateTime.Today,
                RecordModified = DateTime.Today,
                UserRoles = new List<int> { 1 },
                UserActiveIndicator = true
            },
            new()
            {
                UserId = 6,
                UserName = "MeeToo",
                UserEmail = "MeeToo@company.com",
                Departments = new List<int>(),
                RecordCreated = DateTime.Today,
                RecordModified = DateTime.Today,
                UserRoles = new List<int> { 1 },
                UserActiveIndicator = true
            },
            new()
            {
                UserId = 7,
                UserName = "YeeHaa",
                UserEmail = "YeeHaa@company.com",
                Departments = new List<int>(),
                RecordCreated = DateTime.Today,
                RecordModified = DateTime.Today,
                UserRoles = new List<int> { 2 },
                UserActiveIndicator = true
            }
        };
        return users;
    }

    private void Handle_AddUser() => _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(AddUserViewModel).FullName!);
    private ObservableCollection<ObservableObject> tabItems;
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableObject> TabItems
    {
        get => tabItems; set => SetProperty(ref tabItems, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Less code would be easier to help.